# apple app submission rejected due to protocol 2.1.0 of apple sign in failing (invitation based authentication application)

Tags: ios, app-store, progressive-web-apps, apple-sign-in

I am using Firebase Authentication with invitation links for sign up using either email/password, google or apple signup. Using PWA I managed to create a webview application on android play store with no issues.

The current issue I am facing is apple rejecting my application on basis protocol #2.1.0 (App Completeness) where it describes an error of apple sign in flow that redirects them to login screen. [Apple review to Uploaded App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxwoW.png)

Such error does not occur on all my test flight applications on both iphones and ipads when using the "given test account apple id and password".

The question is whether apple requires all applications to be sign in with no restrictions to user (without invitation links), or such situation is a misunderstanding from the Apple app reviewer.

Any Help would be appreciated, and Hope you have a wonderful day.

Comment: They will use their own Apple ID for sign in with Apple.  They won't use a specific Apple ID that you provide.  Remember that Sign In with Apple is intended to be a privacy protecting service.  The email you receive from Sign In with Apple may or may not match the Apple ID email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is whether apple requires all applications to be sign in with no restrictions to user (without invitation links)

Yes, this is usually the case

you can make a Sign in screen that when the user sign in using Apple this message appears `you should have an invitation to Sign in`

And also provide Apple with another way to access the app as testers.